# What is " companion proceedings" in a conference?

Tags: publications, conference, terminology

“All Web Science track papers will be published in the **companion proceedings** of the WWW conference." (http://www.www2015.it/call-for-web-science-track/)
What does " companion proceedings" mean？ What are the differences of it with the main proceedings?

Answer (score 1):

There's no major difference between "main" proceedings and "companion" proceedings. It just means that there will be a proceedings volume that collects the papers. Perhaps the only possible item might be that it's not a *dedicated* series—it might be a special journal issue that serves as a proceedings volume.

Comment: For a conference, can I say the quality of papers published in *"main" proceedings > "companion" proceedings >> workshops*? ( *>* for better quality and higher influential ; *>>* much better quality)

Answer (score 1):

Often a "main" proceedings collects the papers from the main conference tracks and "companion" proceedings collects the papers of satellite events, such as workshops and such things.

In some cases, only the "main" proceedings is considered as a publication (in Computer Science, at least) and the "companion" proceedings is not.

Comment: What does it mean if those one are not considered as publication? They don't be publically released and no copyright thing?

Comment: @Tyler: maybe they appear as a technical report, not something published by a recognised publisher.